# Maintenance Plan SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a Maintainance Plans that runs a SQL job that is failing but not giving and logs to see what is happening. I am new to SQL and not sure what this job is doing.

Job T-SQL

SET ARITHABORT ON

SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

SET ANSI_PADDING ON

SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the relevant job in SQL Server Agent, edit the step, and then click on advanced - you'll be able to specify a path for a log for the job. After it has next run, it will create a log - and you'll be able to see what it has done, and where it failed. It is a starting point to troubleshooting.

If you are using SQL2005 or later, if you click on Management - Maintenance Plans, you'll be able to double-click on the relevant plan - and get an idea of what it does. Key maintenance jobs including backups, CheckDB consistency checker, transaction log backups (if needed), and re-indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You should check each of these in the Microsoft documentation - for example [SET ARITHABORT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259212%28SQL.80%29.aspx).  One easy way is to search on each SET command in [Google](http://www.google.com/).